# Determening MPMovieController bit-rate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-streaming

Is there a way to determine the bit-rate of the stream an MPMovieController is playing?
I am programming in objective-c on iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, the "accessLog" gives you periodic stats which include the observed bitrate:

```
MPMovieAccessLogEvent *evt=nil;
MPMovieAccessLog *accessL=[moviePlayer accessLog];
NSArray *events = accessL.events;
for (int i=0; i<[events count]; i++) {
    evt=[events objectAtIndex:i];
}
return evt.observedBitrate
```

Comment: Can u please explain in detail about how we can find the progress timings of a video using the above code? Where do we need to use the above logic? Should this be used when we define the MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: I tried to implement this on a button click but i am getting this in the below format. The access log is 10097249, The access log is 10035010. But i want to get the actual timing of the video is played. I have a button down the video.I want to capture that particular timing of a video when the button is cliked. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Above code is to get the current bit-rate of the Stream, not the position. There are other stats in the evt (one of them might give you the info you need)

Comment: You need to wrap this code in a method that gets messaged by an NSTimer.

Comment: @eshalev : Can you please guide me how to utitlize this to switch the URL stream?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the indicated bit rate from event, which is the bit rate of the stream according to the m3u8. To calculate the actual bit rate I divide event.numberOfBytesTransferred / event.durationWatched and multiply by 8.

```
NSArray *events = self.player.accessLog.events;
    MPMovieAccessLogEvent *event = (MPMovieAccessLogEvent *)[events lastObject];
double calculatedBitRate = 8 * event.numberOfBytesTransferred / event.durationWatched;
    value = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:calculatedBitRate]];
    self.calculatedBitRateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My calculated bit rate = %@", value];
```

Comment: I find the above bit rate calculation given by you shows me a very high bit rate value , can you please explain me more on this please .